# Simulink: Error evaluating expression

Tags: matlab, simulink

When I try to simulate ADC in Simulink, I get the following error:

"Error evaluating expression 'sim_time/(fs*10^6)' for 'StopTime' specified in the Configuration Parameters dialog for block diagram 'ADC': Undefined function or variable 'sim_time'."

Where the 'sim_time' variable should be defined and how?

I tried to google it, but what I found is not clear for me. Any help, please?

Comment: As far as I know, you have put that equation in the Configuration Parameter, thus you shoudl define it

Comment: Ander, yes, but I don't know how and where it has to be done. I am for the first time in touch with Simulink, sorry for such an elementary question.

Comment: Well it just depends completelly iny ou aplication I assume, but you are not givin any information. That number is specified by you I assume

Comment: The values of sim_time and fs are given in the Matlab code.

Comment: Try defining it in MATLAB command line (base workspace).